# Run Python script on csv-file with OS X automator

Tags: python, macos, csv, automator

So I'm frequently running a python script that takes a .csv file and creates a .tex file from it (I'm making index cards from a database).
What I would love to do, is to use an Automator Service to run this script on the .csv file, so I don't have to open up Terminal every time I do this.

The python script takes the file name as an argument, as in so:

```
$ python awesome_python_script.py sooper_dooper.csv
```

So ideally, I would be able to right-click on the .csv, select a service and the script runs on that file.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Open Automator and create a new service:

[image: Selecting Service Option from Automator]

Select objects that receive the new service. Here we want to add the right click extension to files and folders:

[image: Apply Services in Finder app only]

On the left pane, select “Open Finder Items” and drag it to the right pane.

[image: select finder items]

On the left pane, select "Run Shell Scripts" and drag it to the right pane below the Open Finder Items.

Change **path input as arguments** and add the following code in the input box.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    python <path to script> "$f"
done
```